# Creating a sub-domain on a server giving 500 Internal Error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, internal-server-error, subdomain

I have a website `crucialappconcepts.com`. It is up and working okay and it is created in wordpress.

I created a sub-domain themonolith.crucialappconcepts.com and it has a static website but it is giving me 500 Internal Error. Any guesses?

[image]

Any ideas what might have caused the error?

Comment: Can you look in your server's error log and find the error that was logged for this 500 error? That would give you a lot more information about what's going on.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut where is the server's error log?

Comment: Depends on your web server. Apache stores it under /var/log/apache2. WordPress might also have a custom log location.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to *cPanel > MultiPHP Manager(under software)*, change PHP version to alt-php44 or ea-php56.
Hope this will work.

Comment: Can you explain why this change should help?

Comment: Sometimes there is an issue with hosting servers/providers, as soon as we change our version of php it works fine.